# How to bind MediaPlayer Service to multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, nullpointerexception

I am creating a music player application. I have created a `MediaPlayerService` class and that has been working fine in `MainActivity`. But I don't know how to pass that service without making it null and pass it to another activity, because I wanted to control it from another activity too. If I tried to get it from the main activity class then I got `NullPointerException`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code I can suggest one simple solution: Singleton pattern.
In Kotlin you can define a singleton like this:

```
object MediaPlayerService {
  fun play(...) {...}
}
```

and than use it:

```
MediaPlayerService.play(...)
```

This way you will have only one instance of the object. After creating the instance you can use Kotlin Flow for publish and subscribe.
[here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow) you can read more about Kotlin Flows.

Comment: As you said to use singleton it's working great. But when I try to change the song in the second activity I got ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference``` in this line ```player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),trackUri);```  @Naum PS

Comment: Looks like the Context is null. What you can do is to send the application context when you are creating the singleton instance. You can create a method setContext(context: Context) and store it as a val. Call this method only after initialisation of the sigleton class. @MuthuRuban

Comment: Thank you soo much bro... It's working well. Once again thanks a lot @Naum PS

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it as the correct one. @MuthuRuban